# WDL-OL: resource not found

Tags: macos, audio, plugins

i'm trying to build a simple Audio plugin using WDL-OL (a library that helps porting the plugin on various platforms) on OSX. The plugin builds ok on Windows

as soon as it tries to load a resource background file, i got an ASSERT warning that the file isn't found

> 1 my files are present in the Copy Bundle Resources part
>
> 2 i've tried all kind of combinations with/without subfolder, with caps or not

i'm lost there i don't get why it doesn't find the file

if i create a simple test it works, it finds the file knob.png but with my project it doesn't work

also if i point to the file knob.png (that should work), it doesn't work in my new project, so my guess is that it isn't the png files that are wrong. It comes from somewhere else...

here is what i used in the resource.h:

```
#define BCKG_ID 102
#define BCKG_FN "resources/img/background2.png"
```

and i call the background using this code :

```
 pGraphics->AttachBackground(BCKG_ID, BCKG_FN);
```

please help, thanks

Jeff

EDIt1 : okay i found something interesting

in MyProject-OSXAPP-Info.plist, "Bundle Identifier"  is set to : com.Khaelis.standalone.${BINARY_NAME}

but if i stop the program at the function LoadImgFromResourceOSX(...) and look at the variable "bundleID", it shows:
"bundleID = com.Khaelis.standalone.test"
even if i entered another BINARY_NAME (in MyProject.xcconfig)

how come ? the compiler doesn't apply the name i put.

the variable "bundleID" should be com.Khaelis.standalone.PerfectEQ not com.Khaelis.standalone.test

is there a file that i should update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found it

if you ever encounter this kind of error (resource not found) check if the Bundle Name (in resource.h) and BINARY_NAME (in Project.xcconfig) are the same

then it should work

Jeff